# Applying for PhD as a transferred undergraduate: do I need transcripts from my previous institution?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, application, transfer-student

I am an undergraduate student planning to apply for Ph.D.

The thing is that I spent the first year of my undergraduate at another university. I did transfer some credits but I didn't transfer any major credits. The question is - do I need to include my transcript for the first year in the application? Or could it be based on the institute I am applying to? The GPA of my first year is not bad but getting the transcript is a little bit tricky since the institue is in another country.

I really appreciate your input!

Answer (score 2):

They will probably ask for it.

That being said this is a question for the institution you are applying to. Send an email or call their graduate college to figure out what is necessary in your particular case.

Comment: The portal should make it clear if they want it. Do log in and start an application before emailing someone.

Answer (score 1):

As CL40 said, you will probably need to submit all of your transcripts (this is almost certainly the case in the US at least). I think most schools have this information on their admission webpage (check the FAQ as well). If it is written something like "transcripts from all of the programs attended", then it means you need to send them that transcript. It wouldn't hurt to email/call and ask though.

About your grades, I wouldn't worry about it. It's your 1st year grades, which count for very little (if at all), and you're saying it's not terrible, so I don't think that'd hurt your application. (More senior people here on SE can have more reliable comments on this though. I've never been on the other side of the application game.)